Is it possible to determine the focal length of a concave mirror given two magnifications at two distances?
I came across this problem while studying optics:

A concave mirror produces an inverted image that is twice the size of the object. If the object is moved 5 cm towards the mirror, the image becomes three times the size of the object. The focal length of the mirror is:

The text goes on to say that the focal length cannot be determined, but I already had solved it and I don't know if it really is impossible to find the focal length given these parameters.
My thinking went:
-2 = -di/do
-3 = -di/(do + 5 cm)
Then, I solved for do in the second equation
-3(do + 5) = -di
-3do -15 = -di
-3do = -di + 15
do = (-di + 15) / -3
do = (di + 15) / 3
-2 = -di / ((di + 15) / 3)
-2(0.3333di + 5)
-2/3(di) - 10 = -di
1/3(di) = 10
di = 30
-2 = -30/do
do = 15 cm.
Is there anything wrong with my reasoning, or is the text wrong? Can this be applied to other optics problems as well?

Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference. Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Yes, there is only one big mistake in your assumption. How are you considering that when the $d_{object} $ changes, the $d_{image}$ is not changing?
Whenever, the object distance changes, image distance has to change. You can't equate di from the other equation.
Hope that helps. Please upvote if it did.
